# Use Jquery to show form when clicking "Add Object" button in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make an "Add Car" button that when clicked shows the form that the user uses to add a car to their profile.  I think I have the jQuery right, but I'm unsure of how to connect the button id and form to the script to make it work right.  I currently have:

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info" %>
      <%= render 'shared/user_info' %> 
    </section>
    <%= link_to "Add Car", shared/car_form, id: "add", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %> //button that I want to hide/show the form

    <section class="car_form">
      <%= render 'shared/car_form' %> // current version that shows the form without having to click a button
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>My Cars</h3>
    <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
  </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">     
     $(document).ready(function() {

       $('shared/car_form').hide();   // inserted form id, hides form
        $('add').click(function() {   // inserted button id
         $('shared/car_form').show(); // inserted form id, shows form
     });
   });
</script>
```

And here is the car form, located in the "shared" folder
**_car_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@car, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <h3> Add Your Car</h3>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :year, placeholder: "Year i.e. '1993" %>
    <%= f.text_area :brand, placeholder: "Brand i.e. 'Ford'"%>
    <%= f.text_area :model, placeholder: "Model i.e. 'Mustang'" %>
    <%= f.text_area :vin, placeholder: "17 digit VIN number" %>
    <%= f.text_area :mileage, placeholder: "Current Car Mileage" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Car", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#car_picture').bind('change', function() {
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

jQuery has been added to the gem file and installed.  Need help implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click',function(evt) {
    $('.car_form').show();
});
```

Comment: Could you add how to edit the button in home.html.erb above?  I can't get the syntax right for a button that only hides the list and has an id, rather than having a submit action or something.